# GLFW Linker errors in Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, linker-errors, glfw

I'm having trouble setting up GLFW on Visual Studio 10.0
I was following [this guys](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/316102-glfw-linking-problems/) tutorial. However I am still getting linking errors

```
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwClearWindowHints already defined in window.obj
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwClearInput already defined in window.obj
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwInputKey already defined in window.obj
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwInputChar already defined in window.obj
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwInputMouseClick already defined in window.obj
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwChooseFBConfig already defined in window.obj
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwInputDeactivation already defined in window.obj
1>GLFW.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwInitialized already defined in init.obj
1>GLFW.lib(glext.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwParseGLVersion already defined in glext.obj
1>GLFW.lib(glext.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwStringInExtensionString already defined in glext.obj
1>GLFW.lib(glext.obj) : error LNK2005: __glfwRefreshContextParams already defined in glext.obj
1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

I have tried googling the errors but I havent found much help.
I have linked opengl32/lib and glu32.lib in the linker settings. 
I have also linked the appropriate folders for include and lib.
I downloaded and linked both the win32 binaries and the original zip from the GLFW site.

[code](http://pastebin.com/KyVTWtFK)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is kinda outdated (posted 27 April 2005). You probably added some source files twice to two different projects, thus the complaints about already existing definitions of symbols.

It seems that GLFW 2.7.x does not include MSVC makefile scripts for automatically build everything you need, but if its an option to switch to the latest GLFW 3.0 you could make your life easier because they support cmake:

- Make sure you have both [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) and [git](http://msysgit.github.com/) installed.
- From your Git Bash run `git clone git://glfw.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/glfw/glfw glfw`
- Then open a Visual Studio command prompt and switch to the newly created glfw folder. Create a new sub-folder (`mkdir build`) and switch into this one (`cd build`).
- Now run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" ..` which generates the project files for compiling GLFW.
- Open that project file and compile everything you need (only the GLFW sub-project is required)

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm kinda new to VS.

Comment: You find the Visual Studio developer command prompt in your start menu. Its just a usual cmd.exe instance but with some environment variables setup to allow use of the compiler from the console.

Comment: got it, but what would I type in to call it? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: you need to switch to the folder where you extracted the GLFW zip file to using cd c:\path\to\glfw and then type compile.bat

Comment: it says "GOTO was unexpected at this time"

Comment: damn it, you're right, they changed it since I last compiled GLFW.. I'm looking into it right now mhmm

Comment: The compile.bat file requires two additional arguments "nmake" and "msvc", but there is a file missing in that package, so I only see 3 options: 1. use the binary package (suboptimal) 2. manually compile GLFW (similar to that tutorial) or move to GLFW 3.0 which uses cmake. Would that be an option for you?